# Symfony 2.0: How to correctly delegate user authentication to a separate service?

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony

In the Symfony 2.0 web app I'm helping to develop, we're using a custom-written service for user authentication that's used separately from the app itself. I need to implement the authentication\authorization for the app using this service.

I've read the "Security" chapter of the Symfony 2 book, as well as the cookbok entries concerning the creation of custom user and authentication providers. Unfortunaly, it seems that I can't just create the custom user provider, because there's no way I can just use the service to retrieve the user's data by login. I can only submit the user's login/password and see if the service authenticates him.

Which is why I thought of writing a custom authentication provider. The thing is, after reading the cookbook entry, I'm not completely sure that if I write an authentication provider that doesn't use user provider at all, the framework's code which uses the authentication provider won't attempt to create - and make use of - the user provider (I suppose that if it will, it'll just instantiate and use some default one?).

Does anyone have any thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are on the right track. You will create your [custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) and also create a [custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html). Since it seems that your user provider won't actually need to access any data source it will be fairly empty. Probably just return a new User object with the username that was given.

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    return new User($username);
}
```

Comment: What about the user's password? Will the framework really not try to do something with it in its dark corners that will affect the authentication process?

Comment: I still haven't tested if the approach you suggested works, as we had 4 holidays in a row, but I'll definitely try it out in the course of the upcoming week.

Comment: I still haven't tested it all out, as I had to dig into the Symfony's sources some more, but I think this part'll work quite fine. Many thanks.

Comment: I have concern too. No web service will provide password & other data based only on only username. Is there any solution for this? or how to i get login form password value in loadUserByUsername() function ?